# Average over a period of time is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I'm trying to compute multiple average ( one per id ) over a time period of time with postgresql.

I have a working query but it's very very slow. ( 3minutes on my laptop , 30 second on the server.. )

What i'm trying to do is compute the average over the last X days. There might date gaps ( for saturday and sunday where there is no data ) but i still need the last X. So for example 1month would be 20days , etc.

In order to do so i've been using `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id  ORDER BY tdate DESC)` and selecting only `BETWEEN 0 AND X` ( X being the max number of date that i need )

My full query is :

```
SELECT x.item_id AS id,avg(x.value) AS result FROM 

(SELECT il.item_id, il.value,  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY 
il.item_id  ORDER BY il.tdate DESC) rn 

FROM item_prices il) x

WHERE x.rn BETWEEN 0 AND 50 GROUP BY x.item_id order by x.item_id ASC;
```

As i said my issue is that it's extremely slow. I'm suspecting PSQL is recomputing the `SELECT il.item_id, il.value,  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY il.item_id  ORDER BY il.tdate DESC` for every id and that's why it's so slow.

I've been reading about average and tried somethings ( [this](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average) ) but have been unsuccessful.

Would somebody know how to make the query faster ?

My table looks like this :

`ID,item_id,value,tdate`

EXPLAIN :

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=7707688.82..8934895.66 rows=36453 width=36)
  Group Key: x.item_id
   ->  Subquery Scan on x  (cost=7707688.82..8933564.38 rows=175125 width=14)
    Filter: ((x.rn >= 1) AND (x.rn <= 50))
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=7707688.82..8408189.14 rows=35025016 width=26)
          ->  Sort  (cost=7707688.82..7795251.36 rows=35025016 width=18)
                Sort Key: il.item_id, il.tdate DESC
                ->  Seq Scan on item_prices il  (cost=0.00..1163862.16 rows=35025016 width=18)
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want the last *n* days?  Or do you want the last *n* rows for each item_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i'm trying to do is compute the average over the last X days.

This would suggest:

```
SELECT ip.item_id AS id, avg(x.value) AS result
FROM item_prices ip
WHERE ip.tdate <= current_date AND
      ip.tdate > current_date - X * interval '1 day'
GROUP BY ip.item_id;
```

I don't see what your actual query has to do with the question you are asking, though.

Comment: Because i need the last " dates " not days, so that was my thought process also it's not from current date but from max(date) but that wouldn't change the validity of your query on that side ,  the problems would arise if i need 50 dates but when `50 * interval '1 day' ` would equal in 40 dates because there is no date on week ends , not data in X or Y holidays , etc..  That's why i explained that there might be date gaps but i still need a static amount of "date" - i'm gonna try your query with max(tdate) because i'm not sure if intervals behave exactly the way i think they do.

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding the following index to the `item_prices` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON item_prices (item_id, tdate, value);
```

This might speed up the partitioning taking place in `ROW_NUMBER`, and so would improve the performance of the inner query.  Regarding finding the average, there is no avoiding touching every value in scope for each `item_id`, so there may not be much else which can be done.

Actually, there is one other slight optimization.  You may remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the inner query, which serves no purpose (and won't even "stick"):

```
SELECT
    x.item_id AS id,
    AVG(x.value) AS result
FROM 
(
    SELECT il.item_id, il.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY il.item_id ORDER BY il.tdate DESC) rn 
    FROM item_prices il
) x
WHERE
    x.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 50     -- row number starts at 1, not 0
GROUP BY
    x.item_id
ORDER BY
    x.item_id;
```

Comment: So generally for such calculation (averages) would it be better to just retrieve the values and calculate them in the application ? as it's 40-50x faster ? I'm having issue understanding how to can be so slow and there not be any workarounds better practices.

Comment: Well did you try the suggestions in my answer?  I think it should provide at least _some_ improvement.  No...don't do these aggregations in your application; that would likely perform even worse.

Comment: the index was already there.. :( also as for the order by i can't quite wrap my head around how to remove it as it helps getting it ordered by the latest dates so that it can get the proper 50 last date if removed but i might be miss-understanding. 
Also my primary key is a composit on tdate+item_id could this slow anything ?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` inside the subquery doesn't even make sense, because that order will _not_ persist going into the outer query.

Comment: with and without the order by doesn't produce the same result but i can't figure out why since you're saying the order isn't going to persist. I'll try to calculate both by hand to see what's up